# Having problems changing the font in a table row

Tags: php, html, css

This doesnt work:

```
$display_table .= "<td width='377' height='15' class='ad_headline_font'>$row[headline]</td>";
```

It shows the 'headline' From a mysql field but in standard text... why cant i format the text?

And the table doesnt have a class appointed to it... and style= doesnt work either...

Thanks

the css style:

```
.ad_headline_font {
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #0C9;
  }
```

Comment: And what is the CSS rule you are using to style the table row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the fonts you've chosen.  I don't think those will render in your browser.

I'd recommend you use standard fonts.